# Get multiple result in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am having the following string, and I want to split the string by start and end charachter, the start charachter is format and the end charachter is end, so

```
format_abc_endformat_def_endformat_ghi_end
```

The outcome need to be `format_abc_end` `format_def_end`  `format_ghi_end` I am trying the following regex : `(?:^|\s)format_(.*?)_end(?:\s|$)` that seems to work in [this case](https://regex101.com/r/2JfG6w/1) but when used in [this case](https://regex101.com/r/2JfG6w/3) it doesn't work the way I tought it would be.

Comment: `format.*?end` ..

Comment: What are the pattern requirements? `(?:^|\s)` matches the start of string or whitespace. `(?:\s|$)` matches whitespace or end of string. Your second test case matches the pattern well, there are no spaces inside the string, so `^` and `$` are matched on both ends. *the way I tought it would be* - what is the right way?

Comment: Like I said, The outcome needs to be in either way 
format_abc_end , format_def_end  ,format_ghi_end

Comment: Have you tried https://regex101.com/r/z6c9wZ/1 ? I used a named group here, but actually you don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
format_(.*?)_end
```

The reason you second case is not working is because:
Your second case regex:

```
(?:^|\s)format_(.*?)_end(?:\s|$)
```

> String: format_abc_endformat_def_endformat_ghi_end

`^` = look for start of string. This is one continuous string so if you add this it will match only once.
`\s` = look for whitespace character. Where is the white space in your string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution :) :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string strToProcess = "format_abc_endformat_def_endformat_ghi_end";
        char[] splitchar = { '@' };
       String[] Result =  strToProcess.Replace("_end", "@").Replace("format_", "@").Replace("@@", "@").Split(splitchar);
    }
}
```